# Why are my path functions not returning any images

Tags: python, glob

I want to load some images from a folder and view them one by one, but with one method I get an error message and the other simply doesn't open the images although there are no errors, and the last simply returns an empty list.

I have a few paths variables that I've tried. I have tried both the working directory as shown in `path1` and the other directory which is shown in `pathGlob`. I've tried all variations but I'm using both in different paths to show you in case this matters in any way.

```
path1 = r'C:\Users\Kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\Calibration_images'
path2 = os.listdir('Calibration_images')
pathGlob = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Kays_\Documents\Exam_for_27\Dataset\Calibration_images,*.jpg')
```

I copy pasted 3 folders into my working directory, (and also in another location to try both directories), which I'm trying to call with `os.listdir` as shown below.

```
path2 = os.listdir('Calibration_images')
image_list = []
for filename in path2:
    im = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(im)
print(image_list)
```

This is returning this error message:

```
C:\Users\kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:/Users/kays_/PycharmProjects/CompVisionExam/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kays_/PycharmProjects/CompVisionExam/main.py", line 41, in <module>
im = PIL.Image.open(filename)
File "C:\Users\kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2968, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cali (1).jpg'
```

This error occurs with both `path1` and `path2` (in both directory options), however for `path1` it states:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'
```

To me this implies that the image was correctly located even though it states otherwise as I have not given the name of the file but rather the folder in the working directory, which returns the name of the first image being iterated in the loop, but still to no avail.

When I use `pathGlob` with this loop it returns an empty list `[]`.

I have tried using this loop instead:

```
path2 = os.listdir('Calibration_images')
for image in image_list:
print(image)
img = cv2.imread(image)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(1000)
```

This process finishes with `exit code 0` but does not open any images for `pathGlob`. Nor does the code run long enough for the images to be opened but not displayed, so I'm not sure what is wrong here either! When I use `path1` and `path2` I receive this error message:

```
C:\Users\kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/kays_/PycharmProjects/CompVisionExam/main.py
cali (1).jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kays_/PycharmProjects/CompVisionExam/main.py", line 26, in <module>
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-q3d_8t8e\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

I've seen this error message before in another script and was solved by correctly creating my path variable, which I seem unable to do this time around.

I have looked for help in other questions on the website and random googling but to no avail.

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: `error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'`, check if you can open this image in external app (eg, Windows Photos)

Comment: I have checked and I can open the image manually and also by using something like:
`path = r'C:\Users\Kays_\Documents\Exam_for_27\Dataset\Fixed point\Fixed_Point.jpg'`
`read = cv2.imread(path)`
`show = cv2.imshow('img', read)`
`cv2.waitKey()`

This only works for a single image tho (Sorry I'm not sure how to do the code blocks here) @AcaNg

Comment: @Rekkus Had you tried to debug and looked what is `filename` from `for filename in path2:` line? try to do `print(filename)` after `for filename in path2:` and see what is output?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, @Xitiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here. I'll go through each in turn.

## path1

For `path1`, you are trying to loop through all the files in the directory `r'C:\Users\Kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\Calibration_images'`, but what you are actually doing is looping through each character in the path1 string. To demonstrate, consider this code:

```
path = r"C:\foo.txt"
for c in path:
    print(c)
```

This will print the following:

```
C
:
\
f
o
o
.
t
x
t
```

## path2

The problem here is that os.listdir lists the names of all the files in the directory, but that isn't enough to open the files. To open them you need the path, not just the filename.

To do this with absolute paths, you could do something like this:

```
base_dir = r'C:\Users\Kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\Calibration_images'
image_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(base_dir):
    path = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
    image = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(image)
```

You can do the same thing with a relative path, but you need to be careful about what your current directory is.

```
base_dir = r'Calibration_images'
image_list = []
for filename in os.listdir(base_dir):
    path = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
    image = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(image)
```

This code will work if you run it from the `C:\Users\Kays_\PycharmProjects\CompVisionExam\` folder, but not from other folders.

## pathGlob

You came very close here. All that stopped you from getting the right result was an error in your input path. Try this instead.

```
pathGlob = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Kays_\Documents\Exam_for_27\Dataset\Calibration_images\*.jpg')
image_list = []
for path in pathGlob:
    image = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    image_list.append(image)
```

Note that I have changed the comma after `Calibration_images` to a backslash.

Comment: I swear I've tried that! Something else must've been wrong at the time, but this indeed fixes my problem, thanks a lot! And thanks for the explanation regarding my other faulty paths.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't in the `Calibration_images` folder so you can't open files from there, either change your directory to there using `os.chdir('Calibration_images')` or open like `PIL.Image.open('Calibration_images/'+filename)`

Comment: Using `os.chdir('Calibration_images')` instead of `os.listdir('Calibration_images')` allows me to open the first image in both loops, but when I exit the image I get an error code.
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: Btw how could you see that I wasn't in the folder? I don't think I fully understand when you're in the folder or not. Is it not enough to have the folder in the project folder?

Comment: No what i said was changing directory after listing, it won't work that way
os.listdir only returns the file names it doesn't return filenames with relative directory, so you have to append the file name after directory name (`'Calibration_images'`)